# Getting An Object From A Listview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, object, observablecollection

In my project I have a listview bound to an observablecollection of objects, I have an event that gets the selected item in the listview, I need to get the item as a Card object, not just object. Is there any way to do this?

The object:

```
public class Card
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string CMC { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Set { get; set; }
    public string MultiverseID { get; set; }
    public string Power { get; set; }
    public string Toughness { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Card> SearchedCards { get; set; }
```

The Listview XAML

```
<ListView Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchedCards}" Margin="0,41,1568,0" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource List}"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="List">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Name="ID" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="215" MouseMove="customHoverEvent" MouseLeftButtonDown="DoubleClickAdd"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="90" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseMove="hide"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Item Get Event

```
private void DoubleClickAdd(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            Card item = DeckList.SelectedItem as Card;
            test.Text = item.CMC;
            DeckList.Items.Add(List.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you insert them into the listview? If its as Cards, then just `var card = (Card)obj;`

Comment: Use direct cast: `var card = (Card)mylist.SelectedItem`.

Comment: This about the time you need to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: This is how you do it assuming that you bound your `ListView` to a list of `Card` objects. We cannot help you without seeing your code.

Comment: @RacilHilan I've added the relevant sections of my code, I'd appreciate it if you took a look.

Answer (score 1):

`mylist.SelectedItem` is and `object`, you need to ask your self why. is it just a placeholder or is there a reason why they give you back an object

[Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR
>   boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and
>   stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from
>   the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of
>   boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system
>   in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

The authors of `Listbox` didn't want to lock you into any specific type and wanted to allow you to use any type. Hence the boxing. They store the result in an `object` and let you cast (unbox) the type your self. When you think about it, its quiet convenient not to mention a fundamental design consideration of .net

```
(Card)mylist.SelectedItem
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Var card= listbox.SelectedItem as Card; // If not is card return null
if(Card!=null){

     // Your code here
}
```

As: try yo convert object to type, if not is return null, the object not is type described, then check if it's null ir have value.

Comment: Please explain what you did. Avoid only code answer

Comment: A direct case is sufficient. No need to incur the  cost of checking for `null` and having to deal with a `Nullable` object in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use direct cast (`(Card)DeckList.SelectedItem`), not the `as` operator. You already know the type of the `SelectedItem` object, so no need for extra checks with the `as` operator.

The `MouseLeftButtonDown` is raised before the item is actually selected in the `ListView`. If you want to use that event, you need to first check if the `SelectedItem` is `null` and decide what to do accordingly:

```
private void DoubleClickAdd(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ClickCount == 2) {
        if (DeckList.SelectedItem != null) {
            Card item = DeckList.SelectedItem as Card;
            test.Text = item.CMC;
            DeckList.Items.Add(List.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `SelectionChanged` which is raised after the item is actually selected in the `ListView`. This guarantees you that you will get the last selection (not the previous one) and that there is a selection (will not be `null`). To use it, change your XAML from:

```
MouseLeftButtonDown="DoubleClickAdd"
```

to:

```
SelectionChanged="DoubleClickAdd"
```

I would also rename the `DoubleClickAdd` function.